# How do I get clean output with indented structure

Tags: theming

How can I create a clean theming markup so that the output uses the same indented structure as in my static html template? E.g. when I insert $head;  Drupal uses it’s indenting format.

How can I control the ouput?

snippet from the html.tpl.php

```
<head>

  <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <?php print $styles; ?>

</head>
```

The output looks like this

```
<head>

  <title>Lorem Ipsum | mothership</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal Mothership" />
<link rel="canonical" href="/d7-demo/node/1" />
<link rel="shortlink" href="/d7-demo/node/1" />
  <style media="screen">
@import url("http://localhost/d7-demo/modules/shortcut/shortcut.css?nmdogy");
@import url("http://localhost/d7-demo/modules/toolbar/toolbar.css?nmdogy");
@import url("http://localhost/d7-demo/sites/all/themes/mothership/mothership/css/mothership.css?nmdogy");
@import url("http://localhost/d7-demo/sites/all/themes/itsgoodtobehere/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css?nmdogy");
</style>

</head>
```

instead of

```
<head>

  <title>Lorem Ipsum | mothership</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="Generator" content="Drupal Mothership" />
  <link rel="canonical" href="/d7-demo/node/1" />
  <link rel="shortlink" href="/d7-demo/node/1" />
  <style media="screen">
    @import url("http://localhost/d7-demo/modules/shortcut/shortcut.css?nmdogy");
    @import url("http://localhost/d7-demo/modules/toolbar/toolbar.css?nmdogy");
    @import url("http://localhost/d7-demo/sites/all/themes/mothership/mothership/css/mothership.css?nmdogy");
  </style>

</head>
```

Comment: The important question is: why would you care? What benefits are you hoping to gain by adding a few more bytes to the size of your html? Arguably your html should actually be minified anyway in this day and age

Comment: How do you expect Drupal to auto indent it?

Comment: Why? Due to the fact I do care about it!

As shown above Drupal should auto-indent the code <?php print $head; ?> with 2 tab stops below <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>.

Comment: Nope, Drupal shouldn't auto-indent the code; there's no technical or standards-based reason for it to do so. It makes absolutely no difference to anyone, man or machine. If you're hell bent on making this happen it's possible: you'll need to implement `hook_element_info_alter()`, replace the `#pre_render` callback for the 'styles' element with your own. That callback will need to be a re-implementation of [`drupal_pre_render_styles()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_pre_render_styles/7) that formats the `@import` statements to your requirements

Comment: You could maybe look to override `theme_html_tag()` to make the rest of the tags line up

Comment: The only value added that auto-indenting provides is readability; you can use any web browser HTML inspector for that. And as Clive mentions, the cost here is the # white-space bytes your site has to send. In a choice of bandwidth-performance vs source-readability, performance seems the obvious choice.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML Tidy](https://www.drupal.org/project/htmltidy) can do what you're wanting, but this is designed as text format, Configuration » Content authoring » Text formats which are used in fields rather than the whole site.

Is should be possible with some work to pass the entire theme though HTML Tidy